# Lambda error during maven build

Tags: java, maven, lambda

I am using Maven build to build my project(using Eclipse IDE).
I have put jdk1.8 as default jdk, but still, I am getting an error as the source is 1.6.
Is there a configuration problem I am missing out? Please let me know?

```
   (use -source 8 or higher to enable lambda expressions)
```

1. "clean install" as goals in "Run Configurations" in Eclipse.

2.pom.xml file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mastercard.ayman</groupId>
  <artifactId>Spring_MVC</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>
  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-data-rest-webmvc</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.7.RELEASE</version>
         </dependency>
  </dependencies>


    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-libs-release</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

3. Compiler is JavaSE-1.8

Comment: can you post your pom.xml file

Comment: Change the compiler version in properties tab in eclipse by default it may be java 1.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either set the maven-compiler-plugin as @Horst says or set the **maven.compiler.source** and **maven.compiler.target** properties like this.

```
<project ...>
  ...

  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    ...
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    ...
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: I am able to build now. But on Spring Run I am getting the error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jdk8/Jdk8Module"

Answer (score 0):

This is something I have dealt with too many times.
Could you post the following things as an answer?

1. Your current build command/query.
2. Your **pom.xml** code.
3. Your compiler version.

With these file(s) I could help you further to resolve your problem!

Answer (score 0):

Setting the JDK in eclipse is only half the story, as maven manages the compiler itself.

Try adding the maven compiler plugin to you build configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Able to build. But on Spring Run I am getting this error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jdk8/Jdk8Module"

Comment: Looks like that comes from https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8/tree/master/datatypes/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jdk8 so the maven repo is here https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.module/jackson-modules-java8.  Click on the desired version (2.9.5?) and it give you the pom.xml change to make.